# Disable javascript in browser event handler

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there an event handler for when user disables javascript in their browser, ideally something that could be implemented in/as Google Chrome plugin?

In my case, I'd like to **redirect** user to new page if they were to disable javascript in their browsers.

Comment: *"I'd like to redirect user to new page if they were to disable javascript in their browsers."* Does that mean you require every visitor of your site to install that plugin?

Comment: @FelixKling no. I'd like to build a chrome plugin, but if a user disables javascript i want them to be redirected..

Comment: You don't need to write a plugin, which I would think would be good news.

Comment: You can't do it in a plugin, because plugins are written in Javascript, and Javascript is disabled. Catch-22

Comment: So this is for a user who has already installed your plugin, but then disables Javascript?

Comment: @intelis if you don't help people help you by responding to questions in comments, well, people can't help you.

Comment: I wasn't here, sorry for the delayed response. Yes, it's for a user that has already installed a plugin. I want to know if there are any handlers to act upon disabling plugin or javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `<meta>` tag inside a `<noscript>` block:

```
<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://your.url.com/">
</noscript>
```

Put that in the `<head>` somewhere, close to the top because some older browsers were touchy about `<meta>` tags sometimes (maybe not a refresh tag).